# ClickOnce without custom cultures

Tags: c#, wpf, culture

I have an WPF application that uses custom culture resources and is published to a server to be later installed, or updated, via ClickOnce (I believe).

The problem lies within the custom cultures, which the hosts don't have and the installation comes to a complete halt due to the missing culture.

Is there anyway to force the installation anyway (the application does have checks to register the missing cultures) or to add somehow these cultures information when publishing the application?

---

To give some context, I have the following resources files:

```
Resources.en-GB.resx
Resources.en-GB-informal.rex
```

The first resources file contains the basic translation of the application, and the second one contains roughly the same content but in an informal/friendly context. This extends to other cultures.